# Не запускается телеграмм бот, в консоли нет ошибок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Написал код, запускал, работало. Чуть позже решил снова дописать его и заметил, что бот вообще не запускается, сделал код минимальный и точно так же, ошибки нету не понимаю почему.

Aiogram, установлен через Venv, вот консоль:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\mofog\Documents\telegrambotapi> python bot_telegram.py
(venv) PS C:\Users\mofog\Documents\telegrambotapi> python bot_telegram.py
(venv) PS C:\Users\mofog\Documents\telegrambotapi>
```

---

```python
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types.web_app_info import WebAppInfo

API_TOKEN = 'тип токен тут[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка со сайтом', url=''))
    await message.answer("любой текст ", reply_markup=markup)

if __name__ == 'main':

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - неверное условие в  конце кода.

У вас так:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

А должно быть так:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Вы не поставили нижние подчеркивания и поэтому условие неверное, соответственно строка `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)` не выполняется и код прекращает работать.